# No PackagingProvider found with the ID 'eclipse-feature'

Tags: spring-roo

I'm trying to learn Spring Roo. I installed yesterday Roo and played with it for a while. Today I wanted to continue - I created new empty folder (so it is not https://jira.spring.io/browse/ROO-3030) and when I executed hint I got

```
No PackagingProvider found with the ID 'eclipse-feature'
```

---

```
roo> version
    ____  ____  ____
   / __ \/ __ \/ __ \
  / /_/ / / / / / / /
 / _, _/ /_/ / /_/ /
/_/ |_|\____/\____/    1.3.2.RELEASE [rev 8387857]


roo> hint
No PackagingProvider found with the ID 'eclipse-feature'
```

Not sure if relevant, but I played with some project yesterday, then I executed `mvn eclipse:eclipse` and after that I imported the project to STS (version 3.7.2 based on Eclipse 4.5.1). Today I started working in different folder...

```
> java -version
java version "1.8.0_66"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b18, mixed mode)
```

I'm using it from command line.

Comment: More info would be apreciated ... JDK version, do you run Roo from STS or from shell, the .roo file, etc.

Comment: Thanks, added. By ".roo" file you meant log.roo ? Probably not, there is just command history it seems to me...

Comment: Please, provide more info to be able to solve your issue.